# Parent POM's managed version not respecting version

Tags: maven

I have a parent pom with a managed dependency that looks like

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.psu.cpr</groupId>
  <artifactId>data-quality-services</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I have a submodule with that uses that dependency.  The pom entry looks like

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>edu.psu.cpr</groupId>
  <artifactId>data-quality-services</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

However the compile failed.  When I looked at the effective pom for the submodule the entry looked like

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>edu.psu.cpr</groupId>
  <artifactId>data-quality-services</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

I've looked for something transitive but this is a top level dependency and is only coming in from a single place.

I ran mvn dependency:analyze-dep-mgt but it reported no issues.

Any and all suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you run `mvn dependency:tree` it should show where the version comes from

Comment: Thanks @Zilvinas, I should have mentioned that I had run that also.  It showed it as a top level as I would expect, but it has the wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague had done a merge which changed the artifactId in the parent pom.  This resulted in the unexpected state.